Twillio Call transfer
I am implementing call transfer in Twilio , where A and B are connected via simple non-conference call but now B dials to C and I want A and C to be connected to ongoing call removing B from middle. I tried the conference conversion of ongoing call and then removing B from it. But when B is getting disconnected from call A also along with it gets disconnected. Even though status of call is kept in progress ,
I am expecting help to achieve this functionality as I tried all the ways and am not able to find any solution

The right way to do this is, as you mentioned, to start with a conference call from the start. From there you can add (and remove) participants to realize the transfer. For more detailed help, I suggest you modify the question and show you code and possible error messages that show what isn't working.
